# How to make a chunk repeatable?

Tags: python

I have a function that takes a a list of names and read a determined patch numbers of them(n), I am using yield, my problem is that when the yield is finished the last patch is not of the same size as the other patches. What I want to do is to add to the last patch some elements from the first patch (such that I am repeating) so that all the patches has the same size.

```
first_names = ['Steve', 'Jane', 'Sara', 'Mary','Jack','Bob', 'Bily', 'Boni', 'Chris','Sori', 'Will', 'Won','Li']

def chunks(l, n):
    # For item i in a range that is a length of l,
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        # Create an index range for l of n items:
        yield l[i:i+n]

list(chunks(first_names, 5))
```

If we used the above call, the last patch will be of 3 names only, what I want to do is to let it copy 'steve' and ' Jane' to it, and comes out with 5 names as the other 2 patches.

Answer (score 2):

One quick way to do this is add `n` items to the end of the list used for the yield:

```
first_names = ['Steve', 'Jane', 'Sara', 'Mary','Jack','Bob', 'Bily', 'Boni', 'Chris','Sori', 'Will', 'Won','Li']

def chunks(l, n):

    m = l + l[:n]

    # For item i in a range that is a length of l,
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        # Create an index range for the longer m list of n items:
        yield m[i:i+n]

print(list(chunks(first_names, 5)))
```

Output:

```
[['Steve', 'Jane', 'Sara', 'Mary', 'Jack'], ['Bob', 'Bily', 'Boni', 'Chris', 'Sori'], ['Will', 'Won', 'Li', 'Steve', 'Jane']]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like that:

```
first_names = ['Steve', 'Jane', 'Sara', 'Mary','Jack','Bob', 'Bily', 'Boni', 'Chris','Sori', 'Will', 'Won','Li']

def chunks(l, n):
    # For item i in a range that is a length of l,
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        # Create an index range for l of n items:
        c = l[i:i+n]
        if len(c) < n:
            c += l[:(n - len(c))]
        yield c

list(chunks(first_names, 5))
```